# GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions google+ API shutting down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We received an email this week informing us that Google will be shutting down Google+ APIs on March 7, 2019. Our Web App was specifically named in the email and implied that we are using the Google+ API. Our authentication is done using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google configured as per the following example:

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        });
```

We tried disabling the Google+ API in the developer console to see if it affected our web apps authentication and the authentication does indeed fail so it appears that using this method does use the Google+ API.

Could anyone please provide any advice on how to upgrade our APP to using the new Google Sign-in authentication as it now seems likely that our app will stop working as soon as Google turns off this API beginning as early as January 28th 2019. This does not give us a lot of time to change the authentication.

Many thanks.

Comment: Theres a related issue on github here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6069

Comment: Updates for Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google are being tracked at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251, Chris Ross (Tratcher) posted a workaround for 4.0 but says it should also work with 3.1.

Comment: I have tried the workaround posted by Chris Ross (Tratcher) and can confirm that it does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the workaround posted by Chris Ross (Tratcher) at: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251#issuecomment-449587635 fixes the issue. I was able to disable the Google+ API and everything works.